# Rotating annotation by angle using center point of annotations (with baseline alignment) in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, annotation

Is it possible to rotate annotation (in ESRI Annotation FeatureClass)  by angle so that new position would be calculated based on annotation center point (not alignment, as it is set to baseline, center)?

OR alternatively- would it be possible to change annotation alignment to center/center without moving annotation?

I have thousands of annotations and I would like to update their rotation based on updated angle field in database. All annotations have VERTICALALIGNMENT set to “baseline”.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?  Is your annotation stored in a file geodatabase, or somewhere else?  What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?